# Removing a table row from a db on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I have a table:

```
<table class="table" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn removeButton">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

On the 'removeButton' click I want to remove a given table row (they are going to be dynamically created afterwards). I want to send the data from this particular row with ajax so I can also remove it from a database. I managed to implement the row removal from the website, but I'm straggling with sending appropriate request and retrieving data from the request to remove it from the database.

My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mytable').on('click', '.removeButton', function(events){
    var data_array = $('td').map(function(){
        return $(this).serializeArray();
    });
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        data: data_array,
        success:function(result){
            window.location.href = $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/main';
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Server side code:

```
@app.route('/main', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def main():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    insert_in_db(request.form)
    return redirect(url_for('next_page'))

  elif request.method == 'DELETE':
    #Retrieve data from the request and remove it from the database

  return render_template('next_page.html')
```

How can I send the data from the current table row (the one next to which the button has been clicked) in an ajax request and how can I retrieve it on the server side afterwards?
I tried calling request.data but I get only an empty string. I tried request.form in the DELETE request and this gives me ImmutableMultiDict([]). Any tips? I'm currently using Flask as the web framework. Thanks!

Comment: There is no array to serialize when `row` is created. What should `row` be?

Comment: In this example I'd like to retrieve two elements: Column 1 and Column 2. So basically the data for each column in the current row.

Comment: You will have to create an array and then push each value into the array.

Comment: Ok I could do that, but still how can I retrieve it on the server side? Is request.data going to give me the array?

Comment: I changed the code so that I append all td elements to the array, still I get an empty string in request.data on my server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the row data via the AJAX call -

```
$('#mytable').on('click', '.removeButton', function(events){
    var col1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).html(); // or you could loop through the cells
    var col2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        data: {column1 : col1, column2 : col2}, // post values
        success:function(result){
            window.location.href = $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/main';
        }
    });
  });
```

These should be available in the `request.args`

Comment: Hmm yes, but I'm not using PHP. Do you know how I could retrieve the data with Python? (I'm using Flask)

Comment: Sorry, was just automatic typing on my part. I've changed the answer.

Comment: I updated the code and now print the request.args but instead of data I get ImmutableMultiDict([])

Comment: I found the call that works: request.values returns: CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([('column1', u'5'), ('column2', u'1')])])

Comment: So in order to retrieve just the data we should call request.form. I just don't really understand why...

Comment: It is because, at the heart of it all, the AJAX script is making a request to the Python script which responds back to the AJAX request.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't understand why the data is under form not something else. In the end, I'm not using any forms here?